# Encrypt client connection with squid forward proxy using SSL

Tags: proxy, squid, https

I'm setting up a Squid forward proxy and I'm wondering if I could configure Squid in such a way that the connection from my web browser to squid is https regardless of whether the connection from squid to the destination website is http or https. In other words, I want my connection from my web browser to my forward proxy to be encrypted even though I'm just surfing normal http website through that proxy.

Can it be done?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: how can i do that? are there any information/resource for that?

Comment: Don't really know Squid that deeply, but something involving [https_port](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/https_port/)...

Comment: I personally use nginx as a reverse proxy, and it work as you require. https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

Answer (score 0):

Squid 3.0 has [`https_port`](http://www.visolve.com/squid/squid30/network.php#https_port) configuration directive. See [this configuration example](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Reverse/SslWithWildcardCertifiate) on Squid Wiki for details.

Comment: The config example only covers the "reverse proxy" case. Will it work for a forward proxy as well?