# Can Squid be used as "TLS termination proxy" to encrypt TCP connections using client certificates?

Tags: tcp, squid, certificate, tls, encryption

#### Abstract

I need an encrypted TCP connection from multiple clients to a **single port** over the internet. Can this be realized  with Squid?

#### Concrete situation

We use a monitoring and client management solution in our company which is accessible  over LAN and VPNs. It should be now accessible from **external notebooks which don't use the company VPN**. The communication must be encrypted (TLS). The clients authentication must use clients certificates. The communication is initiated by the clients and uses a single TCP port.

#### Results of my investigations

[NGINX Plus](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/nginx-tcp-ssl-termination/) seems to offer this feature but our **admin prefers squid or apache.** At the squid wiki I found that: [Feature: HTTPS (HTTP Secure or HTTP over SSL/TLS)](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/HTTPS) where TCP encrypting is mentioned. But I also found this warning:

> It is important to notice that the protocols passed through CONNECT are not limited to the ones Squid normally handles. Quite literally anything that uses a two-way TCP connection can be passed through a CONNECT tunnel. This is why the Squid default ACLs start with deny CONNECT !SSL_Ports and why you must have a very good reason to place any type of allow rule above them.

#### Similar question

This question [Encrypt client connection with squid forward proxy using SSL](https://serverfault.com/questions/283053/encrypt-client-connection-with-squid-forward-proxy-using-ssl) is simlar, but doesn't treat reverse proxies / TLS termination proxies.

#### What I need to know

I have only basic knowledge about that technologies and our admin asked me for general feasibility.

- Can Squid be used for save encrypting of TCP connections?
- Can this be realized using authentication with client certificates?
- Or should it be used only for HTTPS connections?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe your admin dislikes `NGINX Plus`because it isn't open source and would accept another well maintained open source product. Then ask him to look at [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html). It is designed for exactly your needs.

Quoting an stunnel example at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stunnel) (for SMTP, but this would fit alos for your needs):

> For example, one could use stunnel to provide a secure SSL connection to an existing non-SSL-aware SMTP mail server. Assume the SMTP server expects TCP connections on port 25. One would configure stunnel to map the SSL port 465 to non-SSL port 25. A mail client connects via SSL to port 465. Network traffic from the client initially passes over SSL to the stunnel application, which transparently encrypts/decrypts traffic and forwards unsecured traffic to port 25 locally. The mail server sees a non-SSL mail client.
>
> The stunnel process could be running on the same or a different server from the unsecured mail application; however, both machines would typically be behind a firewall on a secure internal network (so that an intruder could not make its own unsecured connection directly to port 25).

Comment: +1, sounds very promissing

Comment: stunnel is definitely more appropriate for relaying generic TCP data over a TLS connection than any HTTP proxy could ever be.

Answer (score 2):

CONNECT is only used by HTTP clients to an HTTP proxy to establish a tunnel through the proxy. There's no scheme in HTTP for an encrypted connection to an HTTP proxy either.

I suspect an HTTP proxy is not what you're looking for here.

I don't know if Squid supports TCP plugs with TLS and client certificates but [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) does. It also has the ability to verify the UserPrincipalName in the cert to an Active Directory.

Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who are the authors of WinGate.

Comment: So Squid can't be used for encrypting TCP connections (at least not without any additional plugins)?

Comment: what protocol are you going to run over the encrypted TCP connections?

Comment: TCP with unknown payload

Comment: OK, so you need something that's not going to try to parse HTTP out of it, something that's not an HTTP proxy. I can't find any evidence on line that Squid can run as a generic plug daemon, let alone with TLS and client certs.